# Prove that a polygon is convex over a circle

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

**The problem**

Let $C_A$ (resp. $C_B$) a circle of center $A = (x_A,0)$ (resp. $B = (x_B,0)$) and radius $r_A$ (resp. $r_B$).

For $k = 0,1,2,3,4$, let $D_k$ some points on $C_A$ with $D_0 = (x_0,0)$

Let $D_0D_1D_2D_3D_4$ a non-convex polygon s.t $(D_kD_{k+1})$ is tangent to $C_B$ for $k = 0,...,3$

I have to show that $D_0D_1D_2D_3D_4$ is convex (i.e $D_0 = D_4$) if and only if

$$ d^2 = r_A^2 + r_B^2 - r_B \sqrt{ r_B^2 + 4r_A^2 } $$

where $d$ is the distance between $A$ and $B$. ($d$ can be seen as the smallest distance between $A$ and $B$ to get the polygon convex)

[image]

**My works**

I proved this implication : if $D_0D_1D_2D_3D_4$ is convexe (i.e $D_0 = D_4$) then

$$ d^2 = r_A^2 + r_B^2 - r_B \sqrt{ r_B^2 + 4r_A^2 } $$

But I don't know how to prove the converse : i.e if $ d^2 = r_A^2 + r_B^2 - r_B \sqrt{ r_B^2 + 4r_A^2 } $ then $D_0D_1D_2D_3D_4$ is convex (i.e $D_0 = D_4$).

I tried to prove this by contradiction. I suppose $ d^2 = r_A^2 + r_B^2 - r_B \sqrt{ r_B^2 + 4r_A^2 } $ is true. I suppose $D_0 \neq D_4$ and I have to find a contradiction. Even if we suppose $D_0 \neq D_4$ we can suppose $D_4 = D_1$. Let $D_0 = (x_0,y_0) = (x_0,0)$, $D_1 = (x_1,y_1)$ and $D_4 = (x_4,y_4)$. We start with $x_1 = x_4$ and $y_1 = y_4$ and we should get $x_4 = x_0$ and $y_4 = y_0 = 0$ with the relation

$$ d^2 = r_A^2 + r_B^2 - r_B \sqrt{ r_B^2 + 4r_A^2 } $$

to get a contradiction. But I don't know if this is the correct way to prove...